# LSTM encoder decoder model training errors: ValueError

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, seq2seq

**Resources**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

print(tf.version.VERSION)
print(keras.__version__)

#2.5.0
#2.5.0
```

**LSTM Encoder Decoder Model with Attention**

```
n_features = 129
type_max = 3
n_padded_in = 10
n_padded_out = 10

input_item = layers.Input(batch_input_shape=[None, n_padded_in],
                          name="item_input",
                          dtype=tf.int64)

input_type = layers.Input(batch_input_shape=[None, n_padded_in],
                          name="type_input",
                          dtype=tf.int64)

encoding_padding_mask = tf.math.logical_not(tf.math.equal(input_item, 0))

embedding_item = layers.Embedding(input_dim=n_features,
                                  output_dim=batch_size,
                                  name="item_embedding")(input_item)

embedding_type = layers.Embedding(input_dim=type_max+1,
                                 output_dim=batch_size,
                                 name="rec_embedding")(input_type)
                                          
concat_inputs = layers.Concatenate(name="concat_inputs")(
    [embedding_item, embedding_type])

concat_inputs = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(
     name="batchnorm_inputs")(concat_inputs)

encoder_lstm = layers.LSTM(units=latent_dim,
                           return_state=True,
                           name="lstm_encoder")

encoder_output, hidden, cell = encoder_lstm(concat_inputs)
states = [hidden, cell]
decoder_output = hidden

decoder_lstm = layers.LSTM(units=latent_dim,
                           return_state=True,
                           name="lstm_decoder")

output_dense = layers.Dense(n_features, name="output")

att = layers.Attention(use_scale=False,
                       causal=True,
                       name="attention")

inputs = np.zeros((batch_size, 1, n_features))
all_outputs = []

for _ in range(n_padded_out):

  context_vector = att([decoder_output, encoder_output])
  context_vector = tf.expand_dims(context_vector, 1)
  inputs = tf.cast(inputs, tf.float32)
  inputs = tf.concat([context_vector, inputs], axis=-1)

  decoder_output, state_h, state_c = decoder_lstm(inputs, initial_state=states)
  
  output = output_dense(decoder_output)
  output = tf.expand_dims(output, 1)
  all_outputs.append(output)
  inputs = output
  states = [state_h, state_c]

all_outputs = layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.concat(x, axis=1))(all_outputs)

type_encoder_model = keras.Model([input_item, input_type],
                                   all_outputs,
                                   name="type_encoder_model")

type_encoder_model.compile(loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
                           optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=l_rate),
                           metrics=["sparse_categorical_accuracy"])

type_encoder_model.summary()
```

**Data Preparation**

```
#second input as sequence
type_seq_padded = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(
    data["product_type"].to_list(), 
    maxlen=n_padded_in,
    padding="pre",
    value=0.0
    )

#first input sequence
input_seq_padded = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(
    data["input_seq"].to_list(), 
    maxlen=n_padded_in,
    padding="pre",
    value=0.0
    )

#output sequence
output_seq_padded = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(
    data["output_seq"].to_list(),
    maxlen=n_padded_out,
    padding="pre",
    value=0.0
    )
```

**Data Samples**

```
type_seq_padded
array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 2, 3, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 3, 3, 3],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 1, 3, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 3, 3, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 3, 3, 3]], dtype=int32)

input_seq_padded
array([[  0,   0,   0, ..., 101,  58, 123],
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,  79,  95,  87],
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,  98, 109, 123],
       ...,
       [  0,   0,   0, ..., 123, 109,  98],
       [  0,   0,   0, ..., 109,  98, 123],
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,  95, 123,  95]], dtype=int32)

output_seq_padded
array([[  0,   0,   0, ...,  58, 123,  43],
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,  95,  87, 123],
       [  0,   0,   0, ..., 109, 123,  10],
       ...,
       [  0,   0,   0, ..., 109,  98, 123],
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,  98, 123,  43],
       [  0,   0,   0, ..., 123,  95,  95]], dtype=int32)
```

My LSTM Encoder Decoder model takes 2 input as sequence: items and item-types, and 1 output sequence: items. Last dense layer calculates probability of purchase of 129 different items as next item to be purchased. Model is trained with code below:

```
hist = type_encoder_model.fit([input_seq_padded[:64000],
                               type_seq_padded[:64000]],
                              output_seq_padded[:64000],
                              epochs=1,
                              batch_size=128,
                              verbose=1)
```

And when i attempt to use the model for prediction with code below:

```
y_pred = base_model_X.predict([input_seq_padded_test,
                               type_seq_padded_test])
```

**Test Samples**

```
type_seq_padded_test
array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 2, 3, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 3, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 3, 3, 3],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 3, 2, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 3, 2, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 2, 3, 3]], dtype=int32)

input_seq_padded_test
array([[ 0,  0,  0, ..., 31, 10, 13],
       [ 0,  0,  0, ...,  9,  6,  6],
       [ 0,  0,  0, ..., 13, 13,  9],
       ...,
       [ 0,  0,  0, ..., 10, 51, 18],
       [ 0,  0,  0, ..., 12, 44, 12],
       [ 0,  0,  0, ...,  6,  9, 11]], dtype=int32)
```

I get an error like below:

```
ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1569 predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1559 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1285 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2833 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3608 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1552 run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1525 predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1030 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py:421 call
        inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py:556 _run_internal_graph
        outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1030 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py:1363 _call_wrapper
        return self._call_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py:1395 _call_wrapper
        result = self.function(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py:1768 concat
        return gen_array_ops.concat_v2(values=values, axis=axis, name=name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py:1228 concat_v2
        "ConcatV2", values=values, axis=axis, name=name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:750 _apply_op_helper
        attrs=attr_protos, op_def=op_def)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py:601 _create_op_internal
        compute_device)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:3565 _create_op_internal
        op_def=op_def)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:2042 __init__
        control_input_ops, op_def)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1883 _create_c_op
        raise ValueError(str(e))

    ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 32 and 128. Shapes are [32,1] and [128,1]. for '{{node base_model_X/tf.concat_40/concat}} = ConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32](base_model_X/tf.expand_dims_80/ExpandDims, base_model_X/148834, base_model_X/tf.concat_40/concat/axis)' with input shapes: [32,1,256], [128,1,137], [] and with computed input tensors: input[2] = <-1>.
```

Now, i am looking for a solution for the next error above. I don't know what the folks think, but I really start to hate encoder-decoder lstm. Thanks in advance for your ideas or different model configuration recommendations.

Comment: You are not passing the loss correctly, `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` is a class and you should create an instance of it as `loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()`.Thanks!

Comment: Oh what a stupid error! thank you for your attention @TFer2. I corrected. The model have been trained but i think i have a real problem now with predicting. I will edit the question.